# Serving website assets from S3 to an AWS ECS containing Apostrophe CMS

Tags: apostrophe-cms

We have built an AWS ECS container that holds the Apostrophe App. We have created a separate S3 bucket. The 2 have no problem communicating with each other. This has been tested. And yet the site assets are never able to be retrieved.

We have tried running apostrophe:generate on the container. It does generate the files although sometimes not all, for example the modules folder is missing sometimes. 
We use node app apostrophe:generation --create-bundle=assets --sync-to-uploadfs

I am not really sure what is happening. Apostrophe documentation is limited on this subject. Am I supposed to run this command on each deployment? Is it a one off or not needed at all. (I have set the env variables too. APOS_BUNDLE=assets APOS_BUNDLE_IN_UPLOADFS=1)

I have also run this locally and the generate command seems a bit erratic. Sometimes it generated the modules folder and sometimes it doesn't

This is an example of the output for each file

```sh
net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)
Uncaught TypeError: apos.csrf is not a function
```

Anyone able to give some help for this? Thanks

Comment: Have you checked out this HOWTO? https://docs.apostrophecms.org/apostrophe/tutorials/howtos/deploying-apostrophe-in-the-cloud-with-aws

You don't have to use elastic beanstalk, the principles are the same.

Comment: You should try this again following the updated HOWTO, as we pushed a new version that supports a simplified approach without named bundles.

Comment: This HOWTO is a better choice at the moment, as we need to update the elastic beanstalk one to cover the new approach. https://docs.apostrophecms.org/apostrophe/tutorials/howtos/deploying-apostrophe-in-the-cloud-with-heroku